# How can I get table names in MySql 4.0?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql 4.0.x, there are no view "information_schema".
In this case, how can I list the tables in the database using select query?
without using MySql terminal command such as "show tables"

Comment: SHOW TABLES wont work?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is any way in MySql 4.0. You have to upgrade your MySql to 5.0 to get "information_schema" or you can use "show tables", but that you do not want to use.

Comment: It seems impossible without using informatino_schema, so I think you are right.